# probability mass function and maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, distributions

I am revising for stats exam and have come across this question.  I don't understand how to get the probability mass function in part a and am struggling with part b as well.  For b I have found the log likelihood and differentiated it and set it to zero but can't seem to get the estimator, any help would be appreciated

[image: The question is]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: The self-study [guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) say "Ask about specific problems you have encountered in your initial efforts." -- that is, you need to show us what you did, tell us why you got stuck, and as far as possible ask a specific question relating to your attempt. "I couldn't do it" is not sufficient. There's nothing tricky about it; if you correctly take derivatives and set to 0 the resulting equation in $x, n$ and $\hat{\theta}$ is simple. (Note, however that setting $dl/dθ$ to $0$ doesn't guarantee a maximum, so finding MLEs involves more than that)

Comment: Since it is straightforward (its one of the easiest MLE questions you can ask which is probably why it's in an exam), you really need to show us what you did so we can see what the problem is with what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

The pmf of part(a) is the Binomial, which I am sure you have heard about. The distribution comes from the sum of independent and identically distributed (same probability of success) Βernouli random variables, which are zero-ones variables. You can easily compute the expectation and variance of such variables using basic principles. The hint given then advises you to use the iid assumption of these variables and work on the sum in order to derive the expectation and variance of the binomial distribution.

In part(b) you have to recall what the maximum likelihood estimator precisely does. There are two equivalent ways to derive this estimator, either by working on the Bernouli variables or on the Binomial pmf.

These  hints should help you start. Since this is a self study question, we encourage you to work with our hints and finish the problem yourself.